# Ordenar GridView ASC

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho esse grid, e gostaria de ordenar as colunas por ordem crescente (ASC)
como fazer?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="sqlTeste"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="<%$ Resources:Mensagens, BuscaSemRegistros %>">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FUNDO" HeaderText="Fundo" SortExpression="NOME_FUNDO" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NUM_MES" HeaderText="Mês de Referência" SortExpression="NUM_MES_ORDENACAO" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="COD_USUARIO" HeaderText="Usuário Responsável" SortExpression="COD_USUARIO" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DTA_INCLUSAO" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="{0:g}"
                    HeaderText="Data/Hora Inclusão" SortExpression="DTA_INCLUSAO">
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Você vai ordenar todos os campos?

Answer (score 1):

A ordenação da `GridView` tem bastante problemas, uma solução que pode funcionar é essa aqui:

Adicionar o evento de ordenação na `GridView`

```
<asp:GridView ... OnSorting="gridView1_Sorting" AllowSorting="true">
```

E no seu CodeBehind

```
private string ConverterSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    string novaDirecao = String.Empty;

    switch (sortDirection)
    {
        case SortDirection.Ascending:
            novaDirecao = "ASC";
            break;
        case SortDirection.Descending:
            novaDirecao = "DESC";
            break;
    }
    return novaDirecao;
}


protected void gridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = gridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConverterSortDirection(e.SortDirection);

        gridView1.DataSource = dataView;
        gridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```